# Pushing facebook status updates to application server?

Tags: facebook, push

I'm developing a Facebook application that displays the user's friends and their status. To do so I'm looking for a way for Facebook to push status updates to my app server. In other words, an asynchronous status update notification mechanism. At present the application continuously polls the user's stream using a FBL request, which can become resource intensive as the number of users grows. Any thoughts?

[EDIT] : my application is not web-based but targets mobile phone networks, so there is no live web interface. For example, sending an SMS for each friend status update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language your using but with PHP and a few others you can use the batch(); method that sends a whole load of commands at once and thus using a lot less CPU/Network,
Check it out http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Using_batching_API

If your just using FBML then don't bother, Facebook handles it all.
Hope that helps

Comment: I use Java. Unfortunately batch processing won't work for me because commands would target distinct users, so I must maintain several sessions at once.